# Convert Gray Code to Binary and vice versa

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, binary, gray-code

I wrote this function but can't find out what's wrong can someone help me please. It gives the output as 513. I have added the function for both binary and gray please help Me! Thanks :)

```js
function xor_c (a,b){
    return (a==b)?'0':'1';
}

function flip(c){
    return (c=='0') ? '1':'0';
}

function BinaryToGray(binary){
let gray='';
gray+=binary[0];
for(let i=1;i<binary.length;i++){
    gray+=xor_c(binary[i-1],binary[i]);
}
return binary;
}

function GrayToBinary(gray){
let binary='';
binary+=gray[0];
for(let i=1;i<gray.length;i++){
    if(gray[i]=='0')
        binary+=binary[i-1];
    else
        binary+=flip(binary[i-1]);
}
return binary;
}

let binary=(01001).toString();
console.log(BinaryToGray(01001));
```

Comment: `let gray = '';
  binary += gray[0];` there is nothing in gray to index

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function xor_c (a,b){
    return (a==b)?'0':'1';
}

function flip(c){
    return (c=='0') ? '1':'0';
}

function BinaryToGray(binary){
binary = binary.split('');
let gray='';
gray += binary[0];
for(let i=1;i<binary.length;i++){
    gray+=xor_c(binary[i-1],binary[i]);
}
return gray;
}

function GrayToBinary(gray){
let binary='';
binary+=gray[0];
for(let i=1;i<gray.length;i++){
    if(gray[i]=='0')
        binary+=binary[i-1];
    else
        binary+=flip(binary[i-1]);
}
return binary;
}

let binary='0101001';
console.log(BinaryToGray(binary));
```

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- Your `BinaryToGray` has a wrong `return`: it just returns the argument that was given. It should return the result, i.e. `return gray;`
- The main code passes a number to that function, while the function expects a string in binary notation. The main code has a trace of making a string (to a variable `binary`), but `toString` will produce a string in decimal notation by default. You should pass an argument to `toString` to get a binary representation: `toString(2)`.
- I suppose you intended 01001 to be a binary literal, but it really is one in base 10: *one thousand and one*. You must prepend `0b` to it, like 0b01001.